# React useEffect Not Updating State Properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, async-await, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I am trying to update state in react by conducting an async operation upon component mount.  I have a list of image ids in the `images` prop to start with and on mount the component is supposed to iterate through each of the ids and grab the actual url to the image in firebase storage.  However, the array containing the urls only ever gets a single url in it at a time, despite having many ids passed to it via the images prop.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Panel, Carousel, Divider } from 'rsuite';
import { storage } from '../../misc/firebase';

const ListingItem = ({ title, images, owner, props }) => {
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (const img in images) {
      storage
        .ref(`listings/${owner}/images`)
        .child(images[img])
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => setImageUrls([...imageUrls, url])); // this should append the url to imageUrls
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Panel
      {...props}
      shaded
      bordered
      bodyFill
      style={{ display: 'inline-block', height: '100' }}
    >
      <Carousel>
        { /* This only ever outputs a single image */ }
        {imageUrls.length !== 0 &&
          imageUrls.map((img, idx) => <img src={img} key={idx} />)}
      </Carousel>
      <Panel header={title}>
        <small>foo</small>
      </Panel>
    </Panel>
  );
};

export default ListingItem;
```

Comment: missing `}, [images])` as dependency for useEffect, also you may assume `store` is an async operation, so should await it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useEffect` callback runs only once, on mount. On mount, the `imageUrls` state variable is initialized to the empty array. As a result, inside the `useEffect` callback, this:

```
.then(url => setImageUrls([...imageUrls, url]));
```

will always be equivalent to:

```
.then(url => setImageUrls([, url]));
```

because the initial array is empty.

Use the callback form instead, so that you set the new state *depending on the current state*, rather than depending on the variable in the old (now likely outdated) closure:

```
.then(url => setImageUrls(currentImageUrls => [...currentImageUrls, url]));
```